# Javascript Snippet in ToolTwist Designer is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltwist

I'm trying to utilize the **Page Javascript** tab in the ToolTwist designer but this seems not working. Just a quick test if it is really working, I remove the comment on the alert line but alert is not showing when the page load.

[image: Page Javascript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery in Tooltwist, you need to set the Mode Property of the Page to "Page".

[image: previous]

Currently, the default Mode is set to Legacy which is intended for backward compatibility of  versions of Tooltwist using the prototype and scriptaculous javascript libraries.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. So this means that the default javascript code was intended only for jquery library? Isn't that logical that the default page mode should be "Page"?

Comment: I agree. This may be something that needs to be raised up with Tooltwist as a form of enhancement.